# how can i find which version of fbsdk is compatible with my react native version?

Tags: react-native, fbsdk, react-native-fbsdk

I recently installed fbsdk package but can't build it up
So I need to ask how could I find if my fbsdk version is compatible with my react-native version?
My present react-native version is 0.42.3
My present fbsdk version is 0.7.0

Comment: @Marco I just studied the different versions fbsdk and read their package.json file
In there I got to know that 0.7.0 supports react-native version higher that 0.44
similarly studing the others I finally found 0.5.0 is compatible with my react native version
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just studied the different versions fbsdk and read their package.json file
In there I got to know that 0.7.0 supports react-native version higher than 0.44
similarly studying the others I finally found 0.5.0 is compatible with my react native version

Thanks to all who visited my question
And all those who were having the same issue can try this procedure.